# Notifying main thread object when background operation finishes in kotlin native

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-native

I'm building an iOS app using kotlin native and having problems with inter-thread communication.

In my app there is a class that makes an http request in a background thread (using coroutines) and needs to update the parent class state when the operation finishes.    Something like this:

```
class Feed { 
   var items
   fn update() {
      asyncHttpRequest("http://myservice.com") { newItems ->
         CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
             items = newItems
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This fails because the feed object is frozen when passed as part of the lambda function context so it cannot be updated with the new items when the http background operation finishes.

What is the best way to design and implement something like this in kotlin-native?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use atomics for modifying state concurrently:

- [AtomicReference](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13HGSR6MrqLvT7sZ52hP7V7uYMQgqzMNl/view?usp=sharing)
- [touchlab/Stately](https://github.com/touchlab/Stately)